# Modal Images- using directory images - W3 Schools Modal Image mod

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I am working with the Modal Image tutorial on W3 Schools. In the tutorial it uses the image that was clicked on as the picture that is displayed. I would like the modal to display a file from my directory rather than the clicked image. I plan on having multiple instances of this modal on the same page that link to separate files in the directory.

How do I get an element from my directory rather than the var "img01"/"myImg"

HTML

```
 <!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>

 </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```